# Trying to validate if Facebook user exist or not from a .txt file

Tags: php

I have a .txt files that contains a few facebook usernames and I want to check if those usernames exists, i.e if Facebook returns a real profile or if it returns a 404 page. I want to save all usernames that exists in a .txt file.

```
    function get_data($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 100;

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $data = curl_exec($ch);

        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        }

        curl_close($ch);

        return $data;
    }

    $handle = fopen("usernames.txt", "r");

    if ($handle) {
        while ($username = fgets($handle) !== false) {
            echo $url = "https://facebook.com/" . $username;

            $source = get_data($url);
            if (preg_match_all('/<div class="coverBorder">/', $source, $matches))  // If user exists, print its name ($line). <div class="coverBorder"> confirms that the user exists since this class does not exist on Facebook's 404 page
            echo $matches;
        }

        fclose($handle);

    } else {
        echo "Error opening file";
    }
```

I get those errors:

```
https://facebook.com/sanna Curl error: Illegal characters found in URLhttps://facebook.com/asodkasopdkaopsasf Curl error: Illegal characters found in URLhttps://facebook.com/jana Curl error: Illegal characters found in URLhttps://facebook.com/henrik
```

usernames.txt looks like:

sanna
asodkasopdkaopsasf
jana
henrik

Comment: try adding www to the url www.facebook.com, fixed some issues at the demo I tested

Comment: That didn't work. What I had to do was to use trim() on $username.

Now the next question is how do I save every valid username to a textfile? I'd like the text file to be downloaded to my own computer when I visit the website. So I don't want the .txt file to be saved on the server.